# Can a representation over $\mathbb{C}$ of $S_3$ be like this?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We've just learned about representations and I am quite confused. I've been asked, as review, the following question:

> Is there a representation $p$ over $\mathbb{C}$ of $S_3$ such that $p((12)) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 &1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, p((13)) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$?

What do I look for here? I know that a representation is given by a $V (=\mathbb{C}$ in our case$)$ and an operation $a : S_3 \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ or a transformation $t:S_3 \to GL(\mathbb{C})$.

In our case, we were given the second form, where:

> 1. $t((12)) = t_1$, $t_1$ is an automorphism over $\mathbb{C}$ where $t_1(x,y) = (y-x,y)$
> 2. $t((13)) = t_2$, $t_2$ is an automorphism over $\mathbb{C}$ where $t_2(x,y) = (x,x-y)$.

So what do I check about this definition? That $t_1,t_2$ are one-to-one and onto linear transformations of $\mathbb{C}$? What about $p((23))$?

Comment: Hint: consider $t_1 \circ t_2$ and $t_2 \circ t_1$. Can you find their order, and some relation between them?

Comment: I didn't really know how to use this hint. Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $t_3 = t_2 \circ t_1$.

Thus:

$t_3(x,y) = (t_2\circ t_1)(x,y) = t_2(t_1(x,y)) = t_2(y-x,y) = (y-x,(y-x)-y) = (y-x,-x)$.

Now:

$(t_3 \circ t_3)(x,y) = t_3(y-x,-x) = (-x-(y-x),-(y-x)) = (-y,x-y)$.

Note since $(t_3)^2 \neq 1_{\Bbb C^2}$, $t_3$ is not of (compositional) order $2$.

Now, $(t_3)^3(x,y) = (t_3\circ(t_3\circ t_3))(x,y) = t_3(-y,x-y) = ((x-y)-(-y),-(-y))$

$= (x,y)$, that is, $t_3$ has order $3$.

Hopefully, you will see that $(t_1 \circ t_2)\circ(t_2\circ t_1) = t_1\circ(t_2\circ t_2)\circ t_1 = t_1 \circ t_1 = 1_{\Bbb C^2}$, and realize that $t_1 \circ t_2$ must be the inverse of $t_2 \circ t_1$, which since it has order $3$, leads to:

$t_1 \circ t_2 = (t_3)^2$. Perhaps you can think of what to map a $3$-cycle of $S_3$ to now.